# Kate External Tools plugin missing

Tags: plugins, kate

I have installed Kate Editor (with KWrite, which installs some plugins) in Ubuntu 15.04, and I have just realized that the Kate External Tools plugin is missing since version 4.8.
I really need this plugin, and if anyone could show me where to find an older Kate version or even the plugin itself I would really appreciate that.

By the way, I have found in this webpage the plugin, but (my Linux level is average) I am not able to install it: even the first command gives a problem, and you have to click on "actions" in the left bar... If someone could show me how to build it, that would be really helpful...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

A Kate developer here: Unfortunately, the External Tools plugin was never ported to newer versions of KDE and in particular Plasma 5. There were changes in the plugin architecture, and due to some bugs and no maintainer, this plugin got lost.

We would be very happy to accept this plugin again in Kate's git repository, making it an official part of Kate again. But someone needs to implement it or port it to Kate 5. You can find more information in [this bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=299248).

Update 2019-01-31: I am currently working on bringing this back to Kate: https://phabricator.kde.org/D17971 It will take another 2-3 weeks, though.

Update 2019-09-21: It is back, and will be released with the KDE Applications Release 19.12. See:
https://kate-editor.org/post/2019/2019-09-21-external-tools-plugin/

Comment: Some how related, but it would be really nice if the v4 tab layout would be brought back, and eventually the multi-line tab extension, thanks for your work ;)

Comment: By the way https://github.com/Intika-Linux-KDE/KDE-Kate-Tabbar-Patches I will may be submit the bold patch let me know if it's worth submitting or not

Comment: The patches cannot be applied anymore. Kate's tab bar was just changed to a normal Qt tab bar, so it now looks and behaves as all other KDE tab bars... If you want the v4 version back, you need to port the v4 version to KDE 5 again... There is no other way.